# How do I Run Android in a Windows VM in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, android, nested-virtualization

I have a Windows PC with an AMD CPU in which I run VMM Virtual Box with a Windows VM in which I need to launch an AVD from Android Studio.

I don't need an Android VM to run in Virtual Box, Android must run in a nested virtual environment, inside a Windows VM in which the AVD runs.

Since I know that from Virtual Box version 6.1 there's the possibility to have nested virtualization I thought that just enabling it in the system settings would have been enough, but in facts when launching the AVD it just creates the smartphone silhouette, with a black screen which doesn't respond to any input.
[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz00Q.png)

Starting the AVD these two issues comes out, does anyone know how can I solve these?
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Xy7.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEeKI.png)

I need these two level of emulation because I need a repeatable environment to test my software along with Android. Does Anyone have suggestion?

PS: the AVD works fine in the host Windows OS, it's just the guest OS that seem unable to launch the android environment.

EDIT: I know that it's not at all a good way of testing and performance are really bad, but what I need is a repeatable environment for the validation phase of a thesis. My code is a Java program that use Appium to connect my application to AVD; since I can't configure the Appium server, the AVD and my configuration parameter in each tester's machine, I'd like to use a VM to be run once per computer.

Comment: Does BlueStacks meet your requirements? Can you test your software on BlueStacks? That aside, I think you are not going to get a good result if you want to test it on a PC, at least run the VM on a tablet; Or better, use a real Android device.

Comment: Because hardware architecture differences, emulation might be a bad idea if you want to see how well your software performs in a real Android device, keyboard and mouse are very different from touchscreens, and Android devices usually have ARM CPUs, while desktop PCs usually have x86(-64) CPUs, they are incompatible, not to mention Android devices have many sensors that are not present in PCs...

Comment: Follow this guide and see if you can get your Android virtual machine working:https://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/